# MacBook Pro - Language changes automatically , need permanent fix

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I am seeing particular issue with macBook where keyboard language gets changes very frequently. Issue is - i do know the workaround but its happening quite frequently . we can fix this issue by pressing control+command+command and then press shift multiple times. after automatically changing keyboard language , it show below words .....

Is there any permanent fix for this issue ? as it is quite annoying to fix this every minute. 
I also observed sometimes this issue occurs when i use bluetooth mouse(logitech) as well. 
Is there any way to get rid of this language change issue unless i change language explicitly from system preferences ?

**asdfghjkl characters are shown like below post auto change in keyboard language**
 åß∂ƒ©˙∆˚¬ ∂∂∂∂∂∂∂∂ßƒ∂ƒß∂ƒß∂ƒßƒççç∂∂

also - i use below specs : 
**MACBOOK Pro( 13 inch - 2012 Model ) - MacOS Catalina 10.15.4 ( latest )**

in keyboard configuration - PFB screenshots.

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is the wrong site for a question like this. Please migrate it to [apple.se].

Answer (score 0):

You could try and check the preferred languages setting. Maybe you have a wrong speech selected as an alternative language and somehow it jumps back to that. Perhaps it somehow affects the keyboard setting although it shouldn't.

[image: Check here]

[image: This is the settings page to change language preferences]

Here you should check wether there is a second language or something is weird. If nothing works I'd recommend checking if the Mouse is causing this glitch on other machines as well and if it doesn't - consider reinstalling MacOS (?)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue once before and it was an issue with the keyboard. You may try testing the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues where my primary language showed as correct in the GUI but was not actually correct. The fix was going into Terminal and typing

```
sudo Languagesetup
```

Then selecting the language from that menu and reboot.